# OpenCV restore Mat from pointer memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, go, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm sending a pointer to a opencv Mat from golang to c++ using cgo, and restoring it as a Mat in c++ for use in tensorflow inference.

Once the Mat is recreated in C++ I transform it to a tensor and run it through my tensorflow model for predictions (not shown in code below).

This is working, and the image is transferred and usable in c++. I am however getting a huge memory leak every time I create a new Mat from the pointer in c++. I have tried to remove this one line and instead read an image from disk using cv::imread. This does not cause any memory leaks, so there are no issues running the tensorflow model. The issue seems to be when I'm recreating the cv::Mat from the pointer in C++.

How can i get my Mat from golang to C++ without causing memory leaks?

tf.go:

```
func Detect(detectFrame *gocv.Mat) {
    detectFrameSlice_ptr, _ := detectFrame.DataPtrUint8()
    detectFrame_ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&detectFrameSlice_ptr[0])

    C.LIB_predict(detectFrame_ptr)

    . . .
}
```

tf-bridge.hpp:

```
void LIB_predict(void* detectFrame_ptr);
```

tf-bridge.cpp:

```
void LIB_predict(void* detectFrame_ptr){
    // Restore Mat from gocv.Mat pointer
    uchar* ptr = static_cast<uchar*>(detectFrame_ptr);
    // MEMORY LEAK ON THIS LINE ---->
    cv::Mat inputMat(inputTensorShapeHeight, inputTensorShapeWidth, inputTensorShapeType, ptr);
    // <----- MEMORY LEAK ON ABOVE LINE
}
```

I have also tried

```
cv::Mat inputMat = cv::Mat(inputTensorShapeHeight, inputTensorShapeWidth, inputTensorShapeType, ptr).clone();
```

and

```
cv::Mat inputMat;
cv::Mat(inputTensorShapeHeight, inputTensorShapeWidth, inputTensorShapeType, ptr).copyTo(inputMat);
```

Comment: There's nothing on that line that could be possibly leaking -- the constructed `Mat` object only observes the pointer, doesn't own it, and it doesn't allocate a buffer either.